# Prompt to save / quit before closing window

Tags: javascript, electron

- I am making a writing application. Users can open the app, write some text, save their work, etc.
- I am trying to make it so that clicking the `window close` button will prompt the user to  (a) save their work (if necessary) or (b) just quit.
- I am trying to use `window.beforeunload` to achieve this, but find I am getting stuck in a loop, where trying to "quit" makes the same prompt appear ad infinitum.

Here's some code:

```
windowCloseCheck() {
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  e.returnValue = false;
// window.alert('try to close me');    
if(file.isUnsaved() || file.hasChanged()) {
  // prompt - save or just quit?
  file.fileWarning('You have unsaveeed work.', 'Save', 'Quit', function(){
    // OPTION A - save
    file.save();
  }, function() {
    // OPTION B: Quit.
    ipcRenderer.send('quitter')
  })
} 

else {
  // file is saved and no new work has been done:
  ipcRenderer.send('quitter')
}
```

`windowCloseCheck` is invoked when the application is setup, initiating an event listener for closing the window. My conditional is checking if the file is unsaved or has changed from the original.

`fileWarning` is a function that just wraps the electron dialog box, making a pop up appear with two choices and respective functions to call for each choice.

The rest of the code is [available](https://github.com/teesloane/moonview) if I'm (probably) leaving out necessary information. Would be happy to clarify if I'm not being very clear.

[image]

Answer (score 28):

Please add following block inside the function where you have defined browser window(In my case it's createWindow() function declared in main.js)

```
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 400})


  mainWindow.on('close', function(e){
    var choice = require('electron').dialog.showMessageBox(this,
        {
          type: 'question',
          buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
          title: 'Confirm',
          message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
       });
       if(choice == 1){
         e.preventDefault();
       }
    });
```

Comment: This is by far the best way to approach this issue. I've been trying different approaches for a couple of days now and there is always something that needs to by bypassed. This approach however works perfectly and its pretty much the only way to get this done without encountering problems ... at least in Electron version 1.4.15

Comment: This is great but what if i want to show a checkbox in the dialog with something like `Don't show it again?` then i have to pass a callback to the showMessageBox which result in nonblocking behavior which makes this code useless

Comment: Perfect answer Great Job :)

Comment: I tried to use onbeforeunload in the renderer process and I failed. I have also tried using app.on('before-quit') and didn't work. Using the BrowserWindow is the best solution!

Comment: The proposed solution does not seem to work anymore with Electron 7 because `dialog.showMessageBox` is an asynchronous method. Simply replace the call by `dialog.showMessageBoxSync` will fix it

Answer (score 17):

### Answer for Electron 7+

The following is a working solution for **latest Electron**, based on **awijeet**'s answer and **Sergio Mazzoleni**'s comment.

At the bottom of `createWindow()`, below your `win = new BrowserWindow(...)`, use:

```
win.on('close', function(e) {
  const choice = require('electron').dialog.showMessageBoxSync(this,
    {
      type: 'question',
      buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
      title: 'Confirm',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
    });
  if (choice === 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[image: Close Electron app confirm dialog]

Answer (score 4):

I ended up going with using `window.destroy()` to smash the render process to bits (from the main process):

```
ipcMain.on('quitter', (e) => {
  mainWindow.destroy(); // necessary to bypass the repeat-quit-check in the render process.
  app.quit()
})
```

Not really sure if this is recommended as there seem to be better ways to properly quit an electron app.  Still happy to get any feedback if you know a better answer!

/shrug!

Comment: Weird though that `BrowswerWindow.destroy()` would still be needed to ensure it won't have to be closed twice. This helped me though. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

```
 // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 400})


  mainWindow.on('close', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
    var choice = require('electron').dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow,
        {
          type: 'question',
          buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
          title: 'Confirm',
          message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
       });
      choice.then(function(res){
         // 0 for Yes
        if(res.response== 0){
         // Your Code
        }
         // 1 for No
        if(res.response== 1){
         // Your Code
        }
      }
    });
```

Notice that `dialog.showMessageBox` Returns `Promise<Object>` According to [Electron Doc](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options)

And change `this` to `mainWindow`

This is modified answer for original answer to Awijeet

Answer (score 2):

you can add a local variable to avoid mainWindow.destroy(), like:

```
  let showExitPrompt = true;

  // ask renderer process whether should close the app (mainWindow)
  mainWindow.on('close', e => {
    if (showExitPrompt) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the window from closing
      mainWindow.webContents.send('on-app-closing');
    }
  });

  // renderer allows the app to close
  ipcMain.on('quitter', (e) => {
    showExitPrompt = false;
    mainWindow.close();
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Awijeet's solution is just perfect! Bth, thx Awijeet: it saved me hours! ;-)

In addition, if you need to go further, be aware `e.preventDefault()` is spreading everywhere in the code. Once you managed properly the `preventDefault()` you need to turn the variable `e.defaultPrevented = false` to get back to the natural behavior of your app.

Actually, it seems `e.preventDefault()` function is turnind the variable `e.defaultPrevented` to `true` until you change its value.

Answer (score 1):

If the user would choose the save button, then we should save the data and close the window using `window.close()`.
But, With this approach we will get an infinite loop that asks for saving the unsaved work because `window.close()` will emit window's `close` event again.

To solve this issue, we must declare a new boolean var `forceQuit` that initially set to `false` then we set it to `true` after saving the data or if the user decided to just close without saving the data.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } from 'electron';

let win = null;
let forceQuit = false;

app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        // Your window options..
    });

    mainWindow.on('close', e => {
        if (!forceQuit) {
            const clickedButtonId = dialog.showMessageBox(mainWindow, {
                type: 'warning',
                buttons: ['Save', 'Cancel', `Don't save`],
                cancelId: 1,
                title: 'Confirm',
                message: 'You have unsaved work!'
            });
            if (clickedButtonId === 0) {
                e.preventDefault();

                console.log('Saving...');
                /** Here do your data saving logic */

                forceQuit = true;
                win.close();
            } else if (clickedButtonId === 1) {
                e.preventDefault();
            } else if (clickedButtonId === 2) {
                forceQuit = true;
                win.close();
            }
        }
    });
});
```